# Functional requirement

Tags: requirements-management

I have a application about diagnosis and should determine the functional and nonfunctional requirement
So can anyone help me with this question please:
 Is language considered as a functional requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [functional requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirement) defines what the software is supposed to do. A [non-functional requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) defines further expectations independent from the actual features.

Ex:
functional requirement = "software should square the input value"

non-functional requirement = "software should use at max 1MB memory"

Note: This does not have anything to do with "[Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)"

Answer (score 0):

[Functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirement) define what the software will do.

[Non-functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) are any requirements that don't describe the system's input/output behaviour.

Having "language" as a requirement: When you refer to the language of the input/output, it is a functional requirement. In the case you mean the programming language, it is a non-functional requirement.

Hope this helps maybe somebody else.